# Como trafegar dados real-time com JAVA?

Tags: java, chat

O que é nescessário para se desenvolver um sistema de Chat, em que duas pessoas recebam as mensagens em tempo-real, e como estabelecer uma conexão entre os computadores dos usuários?

O front-end já está desenvolvido, porem falta o back-end em que deve haver a conexão e mandar a mensagem para o programa que esta no outro computador.

- Conexão TCP ou HTTP.
- Java SE
- Peer-To-Peer
- Chat com apenas 2 usuarios

Comment: Eu e meus amigos na faculdade montamos um banco de dados apenas pra armazenar as mensagens, então, exibíamos as mensagens numa lista que era atualizada a cada segundo. Se você está pensando nesse app apenas pra brincar, isso quebra um galho, agora se pensa em algo mais grandioso, como um WhatsApp ou o finado MSN, aí eu já não sei como isso funciona.

Comment: Este chat tem um servidor central? Ou é totalmente Peer-to-peer?

Comment: Eu gostaria de fazer totalmente Peer-to-peer

Comment: Java EE ou Java SE ?

Comment: Se for totalmente peer-to-peer, como seria um chat com mais de 2 usuários?

Comment: Java EE e seria apenas 2 usuários por chat(No começo quero fazer apenas dois usuários usando o programa apenas para testes).

Comment: Tentei modificar meu comentário, porem já tinha excedido o tempo limite, corrigindo Java SE.

Comment: Dá uma pesquisa em Java Websockets. Seguem dois exemplos: http://blog.caelum.com.br/websockets-html5-em-java-com-jetty-web-em-tempo-real/
http://www.devmedia.com.br/java-websockets-introducao/30443